# Picard number of a blown up quadric

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Consider a blow up $\pi:X\longrightarrow Q$ of a smooth quadric hypersurface along a twisted quartic $C_4\subset Q\subset \mathbb{P}^4$. I can't understand why picard number $\rho(X)=2$. I think $Pic(Q)=\mathbb{Z}[l_1]\oplus\mathbb{Z}[l_2]$ and $Pic(X)=\mathbb{Z}[l_1]\oplus\mathbb{Z}[l_2]\oplus\mathbb{Z}[E]$ but I don't know how to find $\rho$. Also is it right, that $K_X=-2\pi^*H
+E$ ?

Comment: The Picard number of a smooth quadric threefold is 1.

Comment: @Sasha Could you explain why?

Comment: For instance, by Lefschetz Hyperplane Theorem. Or by cellular decomposition.